# Pay Rate program (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float')

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a 'weekly pay' program and I'm encountering the issue found in the title. If you have any suggestions to make it better then by all means, lead the way. Otherwise I'm just wanting to solve this issue and figure out the actual logic later. Thanks! (I'm also relatively new to python and coding in general!)

```
import time as t
print("Please only type in the numbers")
t.sleep(2)

Pr = float(input("Pay rate? "))
Or = float(input("Overtime rate? "))
Ohr = float(input("Number of hours required for overtime? "))
Wr = float(input("Weekend rate? "))

print("Put in your hours for each day asked.")
t.sleep(2)

M = float(input("Monday: "))
Tu = float(input("Tuesday: "))
W = float(input("Wednesday: "))
Th = float(input("Thursday: "))
F = float(input("Friday: "))
Sa = float(input("Saturday: "))
Su = float(input("Sunday: "))


def Oh():
    if M - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh1 = M - Ohr
        return
    if Tu - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh2 = Tu - Ohr
        return
    if W - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh3 = W - Ohr
        return
    if Th - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh4 = Th - Ohr
        return
    if F - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh5 = F - Ohr
        return
    if Sa - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh6 = Sa - Ohr
        return
    if Su - Ohr >= 0:
        Oh7 = Su - Ohr
        return
    Oh1 + Oh2 + Oh3 + Oh4 + Oh5 + Oh6 + Oh7

Hrs = M + Tu + W + Th + F
T_Hrs = float(Hrs) + Sa * Wr + Su * Wr + Oh() * Or
Pay = Pr * T_Hrs

print(float(Pay))
t.sleep(20)
```

Comment: I think you mean `return Oh1 + Oh2 + Oh3 + Oh4 + Oh5 + Oh6 + Oh7`. You aren't returning anything from `Oh`. You probably want to get rid of all the other `return`s in that function as well, unless you do want to leave the function before that last line runs.

Comment: You're only creating the `Oh#` variables in some cases though, but are using them unconditionally. That'll cause `NameError`s unless `Ohr >= 0` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the entire T_Hrs definition in a float like:

```
T_Hrs = float(float(Hrs) + Sa * Wr + Su * Wr + Oh() * Or)
```

or put Pay definition in float like:

```
Pay = float(Pr) * float(T_Hrs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try the first one, and it didn't work; however, I have fixed the problem and also added in income tax (Australian tax brackets). Again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

2 Things.

1. You might be having trouble with the

   ```
    Oh7 = Su - Ohr
            return
        Oh1 + Oh2 + Oh3 + Oh4 + Oh5 + Oh6 + Oh7
        return
   ```

part as the return is tabbed in to the if statement and there is a spare at the end.

2. Can we please see the code where T_Hrs?

Comment: I've removed the extra return below the massive addition. If you scroll down, you should be able to see T_Hrs. If you can't then it's `T_Hrs = float(Hrs) + Sa * Wr + Su * Wr + Oh() * Or` (at the moment). Hope that helps.